# inserting a list of objects not working in slick

Tags: scala, slick

I am using slick3.1.1
I want to insert a list of objects in DB (postgres)
I have written following code which works

```
for(user<-x.userList)
{ 
    val users = userClass(user.name,user.id)                
    val userAction = DBAccess.userTable.insertOrUpdate(users)
    val f = DBAccess.db.run(DBIO.seq(userAction))
    Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)        
}
```

However I am running multiple DB queries. So I was looking some way to call only a single db.run.
So I wrote something like below

```
val userQuery = TableQuery[dbuserTable]
for(user<-x.userList)
{ 
    val users = userClass(user.name,user.id)
    userQuery += users                  
}
val f = DBAccess.db.run(DBIO.seq(userQuery.result))
Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
```

However this second piece does not write to DB. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+=` doesn't mutate your `userQuery`. Every iteration of your for loop creates an insert action and then promptly discards it.

Try accumulating the insert actions instead of discarding them (NB use of `yield`):

```
val usersTable = TableQuery[dbuserTable]
val inserts = for (user <- x.userList) yield { 
  val userRow = userClass(user.name, user.id)
  usersTable += userRow                  
}
DBAccess.db.run(DBIO.seq(inserts: _*))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this old but since I just fell on it I'll give an updated answer for this.

You can use `++=` to insert a list.

```
val usersTable = TableQuery[dbuserTable]
val listToInsert = x.userList.map(userClass(_.name, _.id))
val action = usersTable ++= listToInsert
DBAccess.db.run(action)
```

This will only do one request that insert everything at once.